# Android buttons in listview

Tags: android, listview, button, dynamic

So i have been researching this for quite a while, and found nothing?

I want to create a listView that dynamically adds items to it with buttons. Is that possible?

If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: use custom adapter to add buttons dynamically

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-customized-listview.html

Comment: Sorry, i dont get it... i just want to add buttons and TextViews to a list. is it that hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like
make a custom adapter. fill your listview with arraylist then use.

```
public void onClick(view v){
yourArrylist.add(Object);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Why is it inside onClick? can it be anywhere else?

Comment: When trying to use that method to add a TextView, it just gives me some random data rather than the TextView Text...

Comment: use to add arraylist.add(textview.getText().toString);

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to create custom or dynamic listview...

[see this complete example](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/dynamic-custoized-list-view-in-android.html)

Comment: Not sure i got it.. im quite new to this concept and looking for a rather simpler example :D

Comment: I cant understand it, isn't there a simple code? All i need is where you create the list view and add the button dynamically to it.